# Fred's ImageMagick Scripts-3DRotation is not working,(3Drotate.sh: line 384: bc: command not found)

Tags: linux, bash, imagemagick

In the Fred's ImageMagick Scripts, I am trying to run 3DRotate.sh but I am getting error msg. However I can run cartoon.sh I don't know why?? please if somebody know about this.. help me...

I am getting error msg like this.

```
   root@vps-1100110-10106 [~/imagick]# ./3Drotate.sh pan=45 auto=zc test.jpg testfile.jpg
./3Drotate.sh: line 195: bc: command not found
expr: warning: unportable BRE: `^[0-9][0-9]*$': using `^' as the first character
of the basic regular expression is not portable; it is being ignored
expr: warning: unportable BRE: `^[+-][0-9][0-9]*$': using `^' as the first character
of the basic regular expression is not portable; it is being ignored
expr: warning: unportable BRE: `^[0-9]*[\\.][0-9]*$': using `^' as the first character
of the basic regular expression is not portable; it is being ignored
expr: warning: unportable BRE: `^[+-][0-9]*[\\.][0-9]*$': using `^' as the first character
of the basic regular expression is not portable; it is being ignored
./3Drotate.sh: line 384: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 385: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 387: [: too many arguments
./3Drotate.sh: line 388: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 389: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 390: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 391: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 230: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 230: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 230: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 230: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 230: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 230: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 230: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 230: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 230: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 576: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 577: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 578: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 579: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 582: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 582: [: -eq: unary operator expected
./3Drotate.sh: line 586: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 586: [: -eq: unary operator expected
./3Drotate.sh: line 646: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 660: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 661: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 662: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 663: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 664: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 665: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 669: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 670: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 676: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 689: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 690: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 691: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 692: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 693: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 701: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 230: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 230: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 230: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 230: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 230: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 230: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 230: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 230: bc: command not found
./3Drotate.sh: line 230: bc: command not found

--- NOT A VALID SET OF MATRIX ROWS ---
```

My Imagemagick

> `Version: ImageMagick 6.7.1-7 2012-06-18 Q16`

Comment: If I type like this I am getting error msg : root@vps-1100110-10106 [~/imagick]# ./3Drotate.sh
./3Drotate.sh: line 195: bc: command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BC is a calculator/maths program and I assume it is not installed on your server. You can ask your hosts to install it.

I assume this is related to your previous post and the operations carried out using Freds codes can be done in Imagemagick anyway you would need to work out what you wanted and the calculations could be carried out with the standard php functions and not bc.

Comment: @Gobi: instead of saying "Thanks", you should rather *upvote* good answers (click the little gray `^` icon on the left side of each answer), and *accept* the best ones (you should now be able to find out yourself how to do that).

Answer (score 0):

Try installing bc: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_bc.htm

(Note that I'm assuming you are using some flavor of *nix).

Comment: @Gobi: instead of saying "Thanks", you should rather *upvote* good answers (click the little gray `^` icon on the left side of each answer), and *accept* the best ones (you should now be able to find out yourself how to do that).